# Need help with minimum cost network ﬂow problems

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, network-flow

Consider the tree solution for the following minimum cost network ﬂow
problem:

[image]

The numbers on the tree arcs represent primal ﬂows while numbers on the
nontree arcs are dual slacks.

(a) Using the largest–coefﬁcient rule in the dual network simplex method,
what is the leaving arc?

(b) What is the entering arc?

(c) After one pivot, what is the new tree solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think for part 
(a) I would select the most negative tree arc as leaving
(b) positive tree arc that connects the 2 subtrees again
(c) no idea